# SetTime not working properly - UFT, Vbscript, SwfCalendar Object

Tags: hp-uft

I have an object SwfCalendar in which I have to set time in hh:mm format. I am using a code similar to the below one.

```
VbWindow("Window").SwfCalendar ("datetimepicker").SetTime FormatDateTime(Now,4)
```

In this case, it sets the time but as soon as it moves to the next object, the time is changed to a default time. Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Note : I cannot use Type for some other reasons. So, as much as possible, I will have to fix the issue with SetTime.

Comment: You've identified your main window as a `VbWindow` but your child item inside it is `SwfCalendar`? - the latter is part of the `.net windows forms` controls. Part of your issue could be that cross over between addins.  I'd suggest you verify you've got the right object with only the addins  you need.  After that, one UFT trick is to add a generic `SwfObject` to the OR, identify your required object and that should enable `.type`. Beyond that explore the `.object' to see what native methods can be used.